# Scala: How to get a Class[_] instance out of Type?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm implementing deep runtime reflection.
Given a universe.Type, can I get runtime class instance for the type? ClassTags won't help me as they lose type parameter information.
Given the following classes:

```
case class One[T](item :T)
case class Parent(id :Long)
case class Child(id :Long, parent :One[Parent])
```

When given typeTag (and possibly classTag) of Child, I wan't to be able to determine, that parent.value runtime class should be Class[Parent]. Of course, I want it to work recursively for more complex examples.

Edit: 
I could have made it more clear, that I'm interested in identifying not the type parameters of an inspected type themselves, but concrete return types of its methods. More precisely, given a `Type` and a `java.lang.reflect.Method`, I want to be able to determine the class that this method should return. I was able to do it for my example using manual type mapping:

```
            val typeMapping = (parentType.typeConstructor.typeParams zip parentType.typeArgs.map(_.dealias)).toMap
            System.err.println(s"type mapping for $parentType: ${parentType.typeParams} -> ${parentType.typeArgs}")
            val methods =
                for (symbol <- parentType.member(TermName(method.getName)).alternatives; if noArgMethod(symbol))
                    yield symbol.asMethod

            val returnType = methods match {
                case Seq() => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"coulnd't find a method symbol for $method in type $parentType!. Programming error, sorry")
                case Seq(m) =>
                    val possiblyGeneric = m.asMethod.returnType.dealias
                    typeMapping.getOrElse(possiblyGeneric.typeSymbol, possiblyGeneric)
                case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"multiple method symbols for $method in $parentType: $methods")
            }
```

But I expect it to fail in any more complex case, for example, returned type T is an alias, or a type parameter of enclosing class, not declaring class, or something else. As possession of a typeTag guarantees that a type is fully instantiated, it should be possible to resolve any abstract (in place of declaration) type to a fully instantiated type. I think the task is too complex/risky to be tackled on ones one, outside of a dedicated library, and ideally should be provided by the reflection API.

Answer (score 2):

If you put type parameters on the class you want to inspect, and then make the `TypeTag` you can use `.typeArgs` to at least get the class names:

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  case class One[T](item :T)
  case class Parent(id :Long)
  case class Child[S, T[S]](id: Long, parent: T[S])

  def junk[T: TypeTag](v: T) = {
    val t = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
    t.tpe.typeArgs.map { a =>
      val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
      println(m.runtimeClass(a.typeSymbol.asClass))
    }
  }

  junk(Child(10L, One(Parent(11L))))
  junk(List(10,20,30))
```

And the output is:

```
class org.example.Ex1$Parent
class org.example.Ex1$One

int
```

EDIT: You may be able to get a more representative constructor by using mirrors.

```
  def junk[T: TypeTag](v: T) = {
    val t = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
    val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val instanceMirror = m.reflectClass(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass)
    val ctorMethod = typeOf[T].declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val ctorRef = instanceMirror.reflectConstructor(ctorMethod)
    ctorRef(20L, One(Parent(22L)))
  }
```

If these tools can't accomplish what you're trying to do, you may need to start looking at macros.

Comment: Edited it to get class instances.

Comment: Yes, but the amount of things I don't know about scala's type system and limited docs on reflection API makes me wonder if this will work for all cases where original type is fully instantiated? will a.typeSymbol.asClass return underlying runtime class for types which a  generic themselves, are defined by a `type` declaration, are singleton types and whatnot? I don't necessarily need it to work for all those cases, but I need to know the limitiations and handle unsupported cases gracefully with a helpful error message.

Comment: There is no magic here. By adding type params and the tag we can see what the code said at invocation point. Otherwise it's just like reflection in Java once you have the class handle.

Comment: As I expected, when I reflect a method return type with the following snippet  I get an abstract type.

Comment: Unfortunately such refactor would not be possible. First, it introduces needless complexity into the definition for a marginal purpose, secondly, the real code naturally consists of many more classes referencing each other and refactoring every generic type in the tree of reachable objects would yield very long and brittle signatures.

Comment: I hear ya, reflection always seems to take a lot of effort and never seems to quite get you where you want to be. This is why I'm going to be spending some serious time soon learning the macro syntax.

Comment: I was able to map abstract type to corresponding type parameters in my example, but it will not work for anything more complicated. I know macros could be better suited for this task, but then it would have to surely be moved outside of the scope of my current project and into a dedicated library.

Comment: I tried to make a structural type defining a method with parameters i could capture, but couldn't use type variables from outside the structural definition scope. It's a tough problem.